# Recognising patterns and turning it into a formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, coordinate-systems, pattern-recognition

On a coordinate plane lets name a move dot A. The dot A moves each day. On day 1, it moves 1 in the x- axis direction. On day 2 it moves $2^2$ in the y- axis direction. On day 3 it moves -$3^2$ in the x- axis direction. On day 4 it moves -$4^2$ in the y axis direction. And so on therefore on day n it moves ±$n^2$ spaces in either x or y axis direction.

Here is the question. How would you simplify the coordinates of dot A on Day n. For the coordinates you must use N and it must be a formula that can work for any natural number n may be also, it must be generalized not something that would be long
 ex) the x coordinate could be $1^2$ -$3^2$+$5^2$....

Please solve this and if you please, write how you got to the answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Since the terms have alternating sign you essentially want a simple form for expressions of the form $\sum_{n=0}^m ( (4n+1)^2 - (4n+3)^2 )$ and since $(4n+1)^2 - (4n+3)^2 = -4(4n+1)-4$ you only need to know $\sum_{n=0}^m n$ to reduce your sum to a simple form.

Comment: -4(4n+1)-4 = -8(2n+1) so shouldnt i need to know $$\sum_{n=0}^m2n+1$$

Comment: Also, it would help tremendously if you could show me how you solved the problem. I hope I dont sound rude. It is just that maths is quite tough for me

Comment: @Stranger: Note that in general we have $\sum_{n=0}^m 2f(n) = 2 \sum_{n=0}^m f(n)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^m ( f(n)+g(n) ) = \sum_{n=0}^m f(n) + \sum_{n=0}^m g(n)$. You must understand why these are true. It is because you can rearrange a finite sum. For example $2(3)+2(4)+2(5) = 2(3+4+5)$, and $(1+2)+(3+4)+(5+6) = (1+3+5)+(2+4+6)$.